# How to remove the rownames from the file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, r-rownames

I have a file which looks like this..

```
"Locations" "X9442" "X5997"
"1" "cg00000957"    0.87    0.86
"2" "cg00001349"    0.78    0.78
"3" "cg00001583"    0.06    0.08
"4" "cg00002028"    0.01    0.01
```

I wish to remove the row names and make it look like as follows:

```
 "Locations"    "X9442" "X5997"
 "cg00000957"   0.87    0.86
 "cg00001349"   0.78    0.78
 "cg00001583"   0.06    0.08
 "cg00002028"   0.01    0.01
```

I tried various things, but I am not able to remove those indexes while doing write.table. Also sometimes the header "Locations" shifts its column. Can someone help me out how do I achieve the above in R or linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the help file: `?write.table` In particular,

```
write.table(dd, file="output.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```